# WordPress create a user profile page for everyone

Tags: wordpress, getusermedia

I am trying to make a user profile page for all WordPress user, so visitor can see each user's profile with their basic information.

`user` is the native `Author` not a custom post type

**for example:**  My custom user profile links

`https://myexample.com/user/joe/`---- will show joe's profile

`https://myexample.com/user/jhon/`---- will show jhon's profile

but my code works for only admin/author is there any way to dispaly

```
<?php 
$ID             = the_author_meta('ID');
$first_name     = the_author_meta('first_name'); 
$last_name  = the_author_meta('last_name');
$user_fullname = $first_name . ' ' . $last_name; 
$nickname       = the_author_meta('nickname'); 
$branch_code    = the_author_meta('branch_code'); 
$index_no       = the_author_meta('index_no'); 
$sp_designation = the_author_meta('sp_designation'); 
$description    = the_author_meta('description'); 
$mobile_number  = the_author_meta('mobile_number'); 
$user_email     = the_author_meta('user_email'); 
?>
```

can anyone help me to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_user_meta function. 
Something like this :

```
<?php echo get_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', TRUE); ?>
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/

Comment: no `user` is the native `Author` not a custom post type

Comment: what will be pass through `$user_id`

Comment: The user_id. You can use "get_current_user_id()" to get the current user id.

Comment: `get_current_user_id()` will show the current user who logged in . but I need the user slug which i currently visiting

Answer (score 0):

I use bellow code to make a custom user profile page hope this help others

```
<?php 

$curauth = ( get_query_var( 'author_name' ) ) ? get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ) ) : get_userdata( get_query_var( 'author' ) );

    $first_name     = $curauth-> first_name;
    $last_name  = $curauth-> last_name;
    $nickname       = $curauth-> nickname;
    $branch_code    = $curauth-> branch_code;
    $index_no       = $curauth-> index_no;
    $sp_designation = $curauth-> sp_designation;
    $mobile_number = $curauth-> mobile_number;
    $user_email     = $curauth-> user_email;
    $user_fullname = $first_name . ' ' . $last_name; 
?>
```